# How to write buffer data to the middle of a file instead of appending to the end of the file?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

I am able to record audio to an audio file by appending buffer data to the END of the audio file with the following code:

```
// AVAudioFile uses the Core Audio Format (CAF) to write to disk.
// So we're using the caf file extension.
file = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: FileManagerHelper.recordingLocalURL(), settings: format.settings)

tapNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: bufferSize, format: format, block: {
  (buffer, _) in
  do {
    buffer.frameLength = 1024 // Tap is now called every 40ms. By default, tap is called every 0.375s
    try self.file?.write(from: buffer)
    self.delegate?.recorderDidRecieveAudioBuffer(self, buffer: buffer)
    semaphore.signal()
  } catch {
    log("Error writing mic data to file.", msgType: .error)
  }
})
```

But is there anyway to write buffer data into the file at a certain position, i.e. time or index in the buffer data?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

According to the Apple Docs:

> var framePosition: AVAudioFramePosition:
> The position in the file at which the next read or write operation will occur.

So you just need to set framePosition to whatever position in the frame you want to start recording new audio data.

Comment: I might be wrong but as far as I remember this will overwrite the existing data. Is it really what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, like the way the recorder works in Voice Memos

Comment: However, setting framePosition seems to cause "error -66568". Not sure what that means